# Sort by date and group by name - latest appointment for every person with names in descending order

Tags: mysql, sql

My table in MySQL 8.0.29 looks like this

| Name | Appointment |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 2022-06-01 |
| Bob | 2022-06-03 |
| John | 2022-06-02 |

I'm trying to get the latest appointment for every person with the names in descending order

The query should return

| Name | Appointment |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2022-06-02 |
| Bob | 2022-06-03 |

I've tried

> SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Appointment DESC) AS temp GROUP BY Name ORDER BY Name DESC;

But it doesn't return the latest dates for each person

| Name | Appointment |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2022-06-02 |
| Bob | 2022-06-01 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP By`

```
SELECT NAme, MAX(Appointment) FROM mytable GROUP BY Name
```

Or otu can use Window functions

```
SELECT Name,Appointment
FROM (
SELECT Name, Appointment, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Appointment DESC) rn) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Missing from table after `rn` in the second example. Looks like this version works even if there are other independent columns apart from Name and Appointment

Answer (score 2):

You should select the `max` appointment date for each person:

```sql
SELECT   name, MAX(appointment)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name DESC
```

Comment: I was wondering how would this query change if each person had more details for each appointment. For example there could be location column and a payment method column. This won't work in that case since those fields would be independent of "appointment" so what would the query be in that case?