# Efficiently get latest appointment for every person sorted by oldest first

Tags: mysql

I already asked this question [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72839495/3841040) but forgot a few (important) details or got them wrong.

My table in MySQL 8.0.29 looks like this

| UserID | Appointment | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 2022-06-01 | Cleaning |
| Bob | 2022-06-03 | Toothache |
| John | 2022-06-02 | Braces |

I'm trying to get the latest appointment for every person sorted by oldest first.

The query should return

| UserID | Appointment | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2022-06-02 | Braces |
| Bob | 2022-06-03 | Toothache |

Using one of the previous answers I get

> SELECT Name, Appointment, Description
> FROM (
> SELECT Name, Appointment, Description, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Appointment DESC) rn) t1
> WHERE rn = 1

The problem is the database currently has 3 million rows and it'll continue to grow so this query ends up being pretty slow.

My plan is to consume the data in chunks so I'd prefer the query having "pagination". Something like a `LIMIT 0, 5000` to get 5000 records at a time.

I'm open to even re-architecting the database if it comes to that.

Comment: Could each person have multiple appoinments within the same day ? Could multiple people have the same name ? This is extremely likely as the data set has 3 million rows. I suppose it'd be more prudent to use a userid besides username ?   On your suggestion of pagination, we can create a temporary table and use a loop in a procedure to get a comfortable number of rows each time and have them inserted into the temporary table . Then check the temporary table when the loop is done.

Comment: Yes. No, can assume the name is unique (changing the name to userid on the post). 
For now i've resorted to creating a new table that just keeps the latest appointment for each user. I know this is causing data duplication and not good practice but I'm just trying to make progress on a personal project.

Comment: If a person can have multiple appointment in the same day, unless we change the data type from date to datetime, or have some id column to mark the chronological sequence, it's not possible to get the latest appointment.

Comment: Hello @SomebodyOn Earth Can you please share the performance results of running such a query ? (EXPLAIN SELECT...) would be a good starting point. We have the chance to see where indexes are used. Maybe you should think of partitioning tables to run the query much faster.

Answer (score 0):

> For now i've resorted to creating a new table that just keeps the latest appointment for each user.

You are halfway there.  Use that query as a 'derived table' instead of making it permanent:

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM ( SELECT user_id, MAX(appointment) AS last_date)
              FROM tbl
              GROUP BY user_id ) AS x
    JOIN tbl AS b ON b.user_id = x.user_id
                 AND b.appointment = x.last_date
```

And be sure to have `INDEX(user_id, appointment)`

I would be interested to see if this and the "OVER" approach both give the same results and which is faster.